# What details about the host machine does python send to the web server while establishing a connection through sockets?

Tags: python, security, network-programming

I am building a passive reconnaissance tool and one of it functionality is to get certificate info about a domain.
What details of my machine are being to sent to the webserver?
The below code is used to get the certificate info.

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
import idna

from socket import socket
from collections import namedtuple

HostInfo = namedtuple(field_names='cert hostname peername', typename='HostInfo')

HOSTS = [
    ('google.com', 443),
    ('yahoo.com', 443),
    ('yahoo.com', 443),
]

def get_certificate(hostname, port):
    hostname_idna = idna.encode(hostname)
    sock = socket()

    sock.connect((hostname, port))
    peername = sock.getpeername()
    ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD) # most compatible
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = SSL.VERIFY_NONE

    sock_ssl = SSL.Connection(ctx, sock)
    sock_ssl.set_connect_state()
    sock_ssl.set_tlsext_host_name(hostname_idna)
    sock_ssl.do_handshake()
    cert = sock_ssl.get_peer_certificate()
    crypto_cert = cert.to_cryptography()
    sock_ssl.close()
    sock.close()

    return HostInfo(cert=crypto_cert, peername=peername, hostname=hostname)

import concurrent.futures
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
        for hostinfo in e.map(lambda x: get_certificate(x[0], x[1]), HOSTS):
            print_basic_info(hostinfo)
```

- Is my IP address being sent?
- Is python sending any user-agent and what other details are being sent while establishing a connection?

Answer (score 2):

While Python doesn't explicitly send your IP, it is always sent with any TCP request. If it isn't sent, you cannot receive the response from the server.

According to http://evanhahn.com/python-requests-library-useragent, the useragent is 
`python-requests/{package version} {runtime}/{runtime version} {uname}/{uname -r}` when using python-requests, but you can override it by setting the request header.

However, you are not using python-requests but raw sockets, so no data is transferred except what you tell it to (and your IP and some metadata for the TCP connection)

Comment: You're completely right about the IP address, but the code as posted doesn't use `requests`, so there will be no user-agent sent.